# Specific task for each async call and promise wait for all

Tags: javascript, async-await

Is it safe to use asyncs in javascript like this:

```
async coolFunction(users) {
  const firstPromise = findPrivilegesInOneDbAsync();
  const secondPromise = findPrivilegesInSecondDbAsync();
//LABEL_1
  firstPromise.then(privilege=> {
    users.forEach(user => {
      if(user.privCode === privilege.code) {
        user.privileges.push(privilege);
      }
    }
  }
//LABEL_2
  secondPromise.then(privilege=> {
    users.forEach(user => {
      if(user.altPrivCode === privilege.differentCode) {
        user.privileges.push(privilege);
        user.hasAlternativePrvis = true;
      }
    }
  }
//LABEL_3
  Promise.all([firstPromise, secondPromise]).then(() => {
    console.log("DONE!");
    //do something
  })
}
```

The question is, is it guaranteed that LABEL_3 - Promise.all callback gonna execute after first and second promise (order in those two of course does not matter) callbacks are done?

Comment: Unrelated to your direct question, but the privilege population will happen asynchronously, so you might run into timing issues there.

Comment: @VLAZ Do you mean that user.privileges might have random order? Or all from promise one at beginning or all from second promise? If that's the case, then I'm totally fine with that. Thou I might be wrong understanding you. I'm diving into Javascript from not so long time. AFAIK if one promise gonna start executing, then second one is waiting even when it's ready, for the other one to finish - cause of one thread and event loop

Comment: I mean that in this function will directly populate the privileges for a user but since it's async if you do something like `user = authenticateUser(data); coolFunction(user); doActionA(user);` where action A requires some privileges, you are not guaranteed to have all privileges when the action starts executing. So, it might throw you out with something like "you don't have permission for A" whereas you *do* but the permission is not yet read and returned from the database.

Comment: @VLAZ aaaa ok :) Thanks for tip, good catch. Thou after all in my original code - which are not users - i'm just gathering data from db and aggregate it as here (two collections) then just when it's done send to frontend. But yes, you're totally right here!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ...is it guaranteed that LABEL_3 - Promise.all callback gonna execute after first and second promise (order in those two of course does not matter) callbacks are done?

Yes, it is. The fulfillment handlers on a promise are called in order of registration. Since your earlier ones are registered before your `Promise.all` ones, they'll be run first.

Example:

```js
function delay(ms, ...args) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(resolve, ms, ...args);
    });
}

const promise = delay(800);
promise.then(() => {
    console.log("first");
});

promise.then(() => {
    console.log("second");
});
```

But it would probably be more idiomatic to use the promises returned by `then` instead:

```
async coolFunction(users) {
  const firstPromise = findPrivilegesInOneDbAsync();
  const secondPromise = findPrivilegesInSecondDbAsync();
  Promise.all([
      firstPromise.then(privilege=> {
        users.forEach(user => {
          if(user.privCode === privilege.code) {
            user.privileges.push(privilege);
          }
        }
      },
      secondPromise.then(privilege=> {
        users.forEach(user => {
          if(user.altPrivCode === privilege.differentCode) {
            user.privileges.push(privilege);
            user.hasAlternativePrvis = true;
          }
        }
      }
  ])
  .then(() => {
    console.log("DONE!");
    //do something
  });
}
```

That would also have the advantage of waiting for any promises returned by those fulfillment handlers before executing the "done" logic.

---

It's probably worth noting that there's no reason for that method to be `async` if you're going to do things in parallel like that and use `.then` handlers rather than `await`. You could do this, though, to keep the processing of the first two things in parallel but wait for them both to finish:

```
async coolFunction(users) {
  const firstPromise = findPrivilegesInOneDbAsync();
  const secondPromise = findPrivilegesInSecondDbAsync();
  await Promise.all([
      firstPromise.then(privilege=> {
        users.forEach(user => {
          if(user.privCode === privilege.code) {
            user.privileges.push(privilege);
          }
        }
      },
      secondPromise.then(privilege=> {
        users.forEach(user => {
          if(user.altPrivCode === privilege.differentCode) {
            user.privileges.push(privilege);
            user.hasAlternativePrvis = true;
          }
        }
      }
  ])
  console.log("DONE!");
  //do something
}
```

That would also wait for any promises returned by those fulfillment handlers before executing the "done" logic.

Comment: Thanks for answering the question and going beyond the scope of it! Helped me a lot